# View - Has no zero argument constructor

Tags: java, android

I'm following the tutorial at https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Basic-Painting-with-Views which states that to get started I should create a view:

```
public class SimpleDrawingView extends View {
    public SimpleDrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Note that up to here everything is fine. I then add the XML layout:

```
<com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp.SimpleDrawingView
        android:id="@+id/simpleDrawingView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Now I've tried to do the following on my own code, and even with the exact code provided every time I run the emulator I get the following error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.company.cw.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor
    enter code here
```

Any ideas on how to solve this seemingly trivial issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with your view. It has to do with `com.company.cw.MainActivity`. If you look at your error message, you will see that it does not mention your view, but does mention `com.company.cw.MainActivity`.

Your question does not include the code for `com.company.cw.MainActivity`, but apparently it implements a constructor, particularly one that takes parameters. **Do not do this**. For starters, it will never be invoked, so it's a waste of keystrokes. Whatever initialization you want to do should be in `onCreate()`, typically after `super.onCreate()`.